# How to fetch a Zend model using a field

Tags: php, zend-framework

**I have a database table that looks like this:**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `texte` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `rubrique` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**Which is PDO mapped like this:**

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Articles extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'articles';

   //this is where I have a problem 
   public function getArticleByRubrique($rubrique) 
    {        
        $row = $this->fetchRow('rubrique = ' . $rubrique);    
        return $row->toArray();    
    }  

}
```

**In my view I want to fetch the `articles` that have field `rubrique == "club"` :**

To fetch all the items, this code works fine using `fetchAll()`:

```
$articles = new Application_Model_DbTable_Articles();
        $this->view->articles = $articles->fetchAll();
```

But when I do it with `getArticleByRubrique()` I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'club' in 'where
>   clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `fetchAll()` to do the job, without needing to write a method just to do that:

**In the controller's action:**

```
$articles = new Application_Model_DbTable_Articles();
$this->view->articles = $articles->fetchAll('rubrique = "club"');
```